how to compute posterior distribution from a hurdle-gamma model?
I am modelling data from spore traps. The response is a DNA quantity, so >0. The is a lot of 0 (3/4 of data). Zero arise mainly from absence of a potential spore source while quantity depends on strength / proximity of spore sources.
The Hurdle-gamma model appear adequate for this data. I did find how to fit a hurdle-gamma model in JAGS and it converges well. However, I am strugling to compute the posterior distibution of the response data Y.
• How is the posterior for Y computed ? I thought of:
  S1[i]~ dbern(P[i]) 
  S2[i]~ dgamme(shape[i], rate[i]) 
  Ysim[i]<- S1[i]*S2[i]

Is that correct ?
• I still have to figure how to retrieve the shape and rate of the gamma from the used parametrization.
My model is:
   cat("model{ # Priors for beta / gamma components, scale parameter r & random factor variance
                   for (i in 1:ng) {gamma[i]~ dnorm(0, 0.0001)}
                   for (i in 1:nb) {binom[i]~ dnorm(0, 0.0001)} 
                   r~ dgamma(1e-2, 1e-2)
                   sigma.a ~ dunif(0.001, 50); tau.a= 1 / sigma.a^2
                # Likelihood using the zero trick
                     C <- 10000
                     for (i in 1:N) { Zeros[i] ~ dpois(-loglik[i] + C)
                                      # make a dummy presence / absence variable that is 0 if               y is < 0.0001 and 1 if y > 0.0001
                                        z[i]   <- step(Y[i] - 0.0001)
                                      # gamma log-likelihood
                                      # where the likelihood is log(1 - P) if y<0.0001 (i.e. z=0) or
                                      # P * gammalik if y>=0.0001 (z=1)
                                        logGamma[i] <- (r - 1) * log(Y[i]) - (Y[i] * r) / mu[i] - loggam(r) + r * log(r / mu[i])
                                        loglik[i]  <- (1 - z[i]) * log(1 - P[i]) + z[i] * ( log(P[i]) + logGamma[i] )
                                      # linear predictor of the gamma mean and bernoulli proba
                                        log(mu[i])  <- inprod(gamma[], Xg[i,]) + alea[comb[i]]
                                        logit(P[i]) <- inprod(binom[], Xb[i,]) }
                                  for (k in 1:ncomb) { alea[k] ~ dnorm(0, tau.a) }
          } #close model", fill=TRUE, file= 'traces.R')

DATA= list(Y= ANA$conc.spore,                      # response
             Xg= model.matrix(~1+PI1, ANA),          # covariates from gamma component
             Xb= model.matrix(~1+(expose>0.5), ANA), # covariates from binary component 
             comb= ANA$COMB,                         # random factor
             ncomb= max(ANA$COMB),                   # Nb random factor group
             N= nrow(ANA),                           # sample size
             Zeros= rep(0, nrow(ANA)))
  DATA$ng= ncol(DATA$Xg); DATA$nb= ncol(DATA$Xb)

